# logparser: use BETWEEN in CASE statement

Tags: case, logparser

I want to display the sum of devices per 4 different groups depending on Last_update value with SELECT CASE statement:

1. Last_update=0: ==> group name = 'Day'
2. Last_update is between 1 & 31==>group name = 'Within Month'
3. Last_update = 999 ==>group name = 'Never'
4. others Last_update ==> group name 'Later last month'

   logparser "SELECT case Last_update when '0' then 0 else case Last_update when '999' then 999 else  case  when Last_update between 1 and 30 then '1' else 31 end end end as Last_connection, sum(nbhardware) as sum_devices  INTO 'output.csv' FROM 'report.csv'  GROUP BY Last_connection ORDER BY sum_devices DESC"

I got an error that I cannot solve:

Error: Syntax Error: : expecting WHEN keyword instead of token 'Last_update'

Thank you

Comment: I have upvoted your question.  Try to simplify your query until it works.  Then add back the complexity of the `CASE` expression and try to see exactly where it is breaking.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of CASE statements in LogParser (as in T-SQL), the "simple" case and the "search" case. You should use the "search" case here:

```
SELECT CASE 
   WHEN LastUpdate=0 THEN 'Day'
   WHEN LastUpdate BETWEEN 1 AND 31 THEN 'Within Month'
   ...
END AS Last_Connection
```